# Matching words with information from a web scraper

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, nlp

First of all sorry if this is in the wrong section, since it wasn't a coding question I didn't know in which section to put it.

My question is:

Let's say I created a web scraper that extracts all the informations from a job posting website. The information looks like this:

```
Row 1 -  Company X , Computer engineer
Row 2 -  Company X , Civil engineer
Row 2 -  Company Y , Data Scientist
Row 3 -  Company Z , Data Analyst
```

I want to create something in python or even excel if its easier that that flag automatically a row or score a company based on some predetermined words.

if engineer is the word in question then the score would be:

`Company X = 2 , Company Y = 0 , Company Z = 0`

If you need any detail don't hesitate. What am I suppose to search online for any kind of answer? Would NLP or Regex help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regexps are enough for your problem. Firstly you should refine your scraped data to make it pretty constant in its format and then you can extract data with regexps. Here is the example for your data:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

REGEX = re.compile(r'Row (?P<row>\d+) *- *Company (?P<company>\S+) *, *(?P<profession>.*)')

rows = [
    'Row 1 -  Company X , Computer engineer',
    'Row 2 -  Company X , Civil engineer',
    'Row 2 -  Company Y , Data Scientist',
    'Row 3 -  Company Z , Data Analyst'
]

found_data = []

for row in rows:
    found = REGEX.match(row)
    if found:
        found_data.append([
            found.group('row'),
            found.group('company'),
            found.group('profession')
        ])
pprint(found_data)
```

> ```
> [['1', 'X', 'Computer engineer'],
>  ['2', 'X', 'Civil engineer'],
>  ['2', 'Y', 'Data Scientist'],
>  ['3', 'Z', 'Data Analyst']]
> ```